# Scheduling alarms with Android 4.0 and latest versions

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I've been using the following code to schedule many alarms on Android 3.0 and previous versions. It worked fine, But the 4.0 and later versions won't work with it (yes .. alarms notifications won't popup). The alarms won't set. At the day and time programmed nothing happens... the notification never pops up =(

Would you suggest any modification? Thank you!

```
private void setNotification(int phour, int pminute) {


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    long when = 0;

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReceberAlarme.class);
    notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("eventName", 
    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    notificationIntent.putExtra("eventDescription",getResources().getString(R.string.notification_phrase));


    long repeatTime=0;

    notificationIntent.putExtra("Flag",true);
    repeatTime=(AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);

    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,thour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,tminute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    if(now.after(cal)){
        //log.d("Notice", "Added a day");
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Delete old alarms
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);

    // Schedule alarms
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), repeatTime, pendingIntent);

}
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "won't work with it" means.

Comment: Thanks. There you go.... any thoughts about it?

Comment: `setRepeating()` is inexact on Android 4.4+. Also, we don't usually use categories on broadcasts, and so that may be blocking your receiver from receiving the broadcast.